# Power BI Slicer Showing More Dates Than Available

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have dates in a set of data.

- The data is in MM/dd/yyyy format.
- The earliest date is: 11/25/2014
- The latest date is 10/21/2021

I am using a slicer in my visualization.

When I click on a date value, circled in my image below, I am able to select dates earlier than my earliest date, see image below:

[image: Date Slicer]
[image: Date Slicer 2]

How do I stop this from going earlier than my earliest date?

Comment: You can check this video {Build a DATE PICKER in Power BI Desktop} from channel [Guy in a Cube]:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhWtU0DynCk&ab_channel=GuyinaCube

Comment: This is a known issue with the default Power BI Date picker